# Not able to upload image to firebase storage from my App

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

It has been days facing this problem. Able to the image by the way.Always shows "Upload failed".My app is connected to Firebase Database and Storage. All other values of app are successfully added to the database. But nothing goes in Firebase Storage. Please help.
My Upload activity:

```
public class UploadActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    StorageTask uploadTask;
    Uri path;
    StorageReference photoStorage;
    DatabaseReference photoRef;
    ImageView passportsize_photo;
    Button upload_photo, chose_photo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);

        chose_photo =findViewById(R.id.choose_photo);
        passportsize_photo =findViewById(R.id.passportsize_photo);
        upload_photo =findViewById(R.id.upload_photo);

        photoStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Photos");
        photoRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Photos");

        upload_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(uploadTask!=null&&uploadTask.isInProgress()){
                    Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Upload in progress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else { uploadFile();}
            }
        });
        chose_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openFileChooser();
            }
        });

    }

    private String getFileExtension(Uri uri) {
        ContentResolver cR = this.getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));
    }
    private void uploadFile() {
        StorageReference Ref = photoStorage.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getFileExtension(path));
        uploadTask = Ref.putFile(path)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        // Get a URL to the uploaded content
                        //Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                        Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                        // ...
                        Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Upload failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                });
    }

    private void openFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            path = data.getData();
            passportsize_photo.setImageURI(path);
            //Picasso.get().load(path).into(passportsize_photo);
        }
    }


}
```

My dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible,GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    //firebase
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:19.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.5'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.3.2'
    //

    //google sign in
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    //glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    //circular image
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    //picasso
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'


}
```

Manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Read many forums and articles, did not find any solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share exception message

Comment: Hi @superstark Welcome to Stackoverflow!! Please, share the error that you are facing, so we can better assist you.